# Compiler for AMD CPUs : C, C++, fortran and BLAS/LAPACK

Tags: c++, c, compiler, fortran

I have been using Intel CPUs with Parallel Studio which bundles icc, icpc and ifort (compiler for C,C++ and Fortran) which are optimized for Intel. Moreover MKL (Math Kernel Library) with BLAS and LAPACK are included in it.

Now, I need to setup a new system running AMD CPU (specifically Ryzen 7).
I need to look for optimized compilers for this platform as well as BALS/LAPACK libraries.

Open source GNU compilers are usable but usually specific libraries are better optimized (as far as for Intel that's the case for example MKL) so something developed for AMD maybe be faster. Could someone point to right compilers and libraries.

What is required : C, C++, fortran compilers, BLAS LAPACK libraries

OS: Debian

Comment: Acceptable price range? Bare metal target or with an embedded OS, if so which?

Comment: I am only looking for software recommendation specifically compilers optimized for AMD chips. Usually compilers are free for academic purposes and I am a student. So I would try to get  them for no price !

Comment: Absoft has a fortran compiler only which meets your requirements - I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD does not maintain or distribute its own C/C++ compiler.

What's more, Intel's C/C++ compiler (icc) doesn't necessarily perform consistently better than GCC and clang. I'm having trouble backing up this second claim, but [here](http://www.nersc.gov/users/computational-systems/retired-systems/hopper/performance-and-optimization/compiler-comparisons/) is a link to a not-very-convincing comparison by PGI, and [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/327585) is a discussion on this matter on an Intel form (already a few years ago). ... oh, wait, [this](https://blog.pgaddict.com/posts/postgresql-performance-with-gcc-clang-and-icc) is a nice comparison, albeit for a single kind of application - a relational DBMS (PostgreSQL):

[image]

So what you have to choose from are basically just (versions of) GCC and clang - which also don't have a clear X-is-better-than-Y relationship. You'll probably need to build with several different versions and compilation flags and see what provides the best results.

If you were on Windows you could also have looked at Microsoft's Visual C++ compiler (although I don't recommend that on principle).

---

Caveat: AMD used to maintain a version of the [Open64 compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open64). That's either in the netherworld or officially discontinued. See [here](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/cpu-development/x86-open64-compiler-suite/).

Comment: einnpoklum is wrong! There is AMD Compiler:
https://developer.amd.com/amd-aocc/